# Slash at the end of the line in haml - should I clean it?

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm wondering why in the source code of my project I sometimes see a `/` at the end of the line ([Haml](http://haml.info/)).

```
%meta{:content => "text/html; charset=utf-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
```

Maybe it's due to some HTML to Haml conversion, but why?

I cannot find any doc about that. Just wondering if I should clean this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It creates a void self-closing tag.

> The forward slash character, when placed at the end of a tag
>   definition, causes Haml to treat it as being an empty (or void)
>   element. Depending on the format, the tag will be rendered either
>   without a closing tag (:html4 or :html5), or as a self-closing tag
>   (:xhtml).

See the HAML documentation: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#empty-void-tags-